# Is there a visual code editor feature that can list current page's functions/methods?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Tried Command-P for a function name on the current TypeScript file, but it did not find the function which, I know, exists on the page.

Went thru docs and but this is a specific need. 
Does anyone figure if such a thing exists whereby you just do a keyword combo and get a list of the current page's function names listed? or Alternatively, have the ability to search for that function name ( to go to its declaration) ? Maybe Command-P, can be extended to include currrent page's functions/methods? That would be awesome..

Comment: What do you mean when you say page? A source file that’s in focus?

Comment: Left panel, Outline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re most likely looking for 'Go to Symbol' feature.

> You can navigate symbols inside a file with ⇧⌘O (Windows, Linux Ctrl+Shift+O).
>
> – [source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-symbol)

Comment: It's not `most likely`. It's `exactly`. :)

Comment: Felicio, do you also happen to know how to go back to the last cursor location with a keyobard combo (and keep going back as long as you do that combo) in Visual Code Editor? The Visual Basic 6 ( of the good old days ) had this feature and I oved it.  I'd like to map that feauture if exists to a keyboard combo that I like. So far what I do "undo" and "redo" to see where I was but this is not only stupid but also limited to the last cursor position only.

Comment: In built-ins, unfortunately not. I opted in for `vim` emulation with [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) 'Keymap Extension'. Now, I’m able to navigate back in cursor last “stops” using Ctrl+O, which BTW works across files too.

Comment: Felicio Fanntastico.