# Visual studio code lists of classes and methods

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to see the list of classes in a module and a list of methods in a class in the same way that it is in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a visual code editor feature that can list current page's functions/methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073474/is-there-a-visual-code-editor-feature-that-can-list-current-pages-functions-met)

Answer (score 1):

Try [CodeOutline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline) or [CodeMap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oleg-shilo.codemap) plugins, they're both valid and covers a lot of languages. They publish a panel similar to what you see with MS VStudio